# How to extract contact numbers from long description field?

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

This is my long input string which contains contact number in between this string like below:

> sgsdgsdgs 123-456-7890 sdgsdgs (123) 456-7890 sdgsdgsdg 123 456 7890
>   sdgsdgsdg 123.456.7890 sdfsdfsdfs +91 (123) 456-7890

Now i want to Extract all input numbers like:

```
123-456-7890
(123) 456-7890
123 456 7890
123.456.7890
+91 (123) 456-7890
```

I want to store all this number in array.

This is what i have tried but getting only 2 numbers only:

```
string pattern = @"^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$";
 Regex reg = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

 var a = txt.Split();
 List < string > list = new List < string > ();
 foreach(var item in a) {
     if (reg.IsMatch(item)) {
         list.Add(item);
     }
 }
```

Can anybody help me with this??

Comment: remove `^` from beginning and `$` from end of you regex, and it shoul work

Comment: @m.cekiera:Getting same output.not working

Comment: Sure it won't: do not split the input string. Pass it to Regex.Matches as a whole.

Comment: ok, what is your separator in txt.Split()? should't it be Split("\s") or something like this?

Comment: @stribizhev:can you please post your ans

Comment: @m.cekiera:Please post your solution

Comment: You need to clearly specify which characters are to be considered part of a number to be retained and which characters are not part of a number. How would you want this string handled "123-456 abc-def 234.567. bcd.efg cde. 345 (678)901 def (ghi) jkl"? There are many other interesting patterns with mixes of these characters `- + ( ) .` that I have not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use regex directly on a String, like:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*");
        Match match = regex.Match("sgsdgsdgs 123-456-7890 sdgsdgs (123) 456-7890 sdgsdgsdg 123 456 7890 sdgsdgsdg 123.456.7890 sdfsdfsdfs +91 (123) 456-7890");
        List < string > list = new List < string > ();
        while (match.Success)
        {
            list.Add(match.Value);
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
        list.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: \s is not working.please check.giving me error.unrecognize escape sequence

Comment: list.Add and match.nextMatch should be swapped I believe.

Comment: @stribizhev you are right, as always, thanks for comment!

Comment: @SanjivRajput there was a bug in code, take a look on `while (match.Success)` loop

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `Split` for this.

Just go through the matches and get their `Groups[0].Value`, should be something like this:

```
foreach (var m in MyRegex.Match(myInput).Matches)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
```

Tested on [regexhero](http://regexhero.net):

1. Regex: `\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?:[ ]*x(\d+))?\s*`
2. Input: `sgsdgsdgs 123-456-7890 sdgsdgs (123) 456-7890 sdgsdgsdg 123 456 7890 sdgsdgsdg 123.456.7890 sdfsdfsdfs +91 (123) 456-7890`
3. Output: 5 matches

   - 123-456-7890
   - (123) 456-7890
   - 123 456 7890
   - 123.456.7890
   - +91 (123) 456-7890

edit: regexhero didn't like the space in the last group, had to replace it with `[ ]`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting two numbers because split() by default uses space as delimiter.

Comment: so what do i do i get the expected output??

Answer (score 1):

Try this tested code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)        
        {
            string txt = "sgsdgsdgs 123-456-7890 sdgsdgs (123) 456-7890 sdgsdgsdg 123 456 7890 sdgsdgsdg 123.456.7890 sdfsdfsdfs +91 (123) 456-7890";
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*");

            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in regex.Matches(txt))
            {
                list.Add(item.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```